# Multithreading using pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, image, pthreads, dynamic-memory-allocation

Actually, I need to use several threads for image acquisition/processing.
Let me explain. I make the acquisition of 100 images, and I need to calculate the average image of those 100 images.

I would to have one thread which acquire images, and the other one which calculate the average.
As I don't have the camera with me, I simulate the camera with opencv. I have 100 images in folder, and I try to calculate the average image of those images.

```
cv::Mat img_IN = cv::imread(path , 0) ; 
img_IN = img_IN.reshape(0,1) ;
```

I can't control the adress of the buffer filled by the camera, that mean that I can't define global variable. If I define a global variable, for example :

```
unsigned char* img = new unsigned char [numberOfPixel] ;
```

I have to fill it by value, that mean :

```
for(int i= 0 ; i<numberOfPixel ; i++)
img[i] = (img_IN.data)[i] ;
```

It takes a long time. If

My question is, can I get the array from an other thread, if that array is not declare as global ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe better to use std::thread, not pthread.

Comment: Why don't you just use OpenCV's built-in `add()` function to add each new image to a *"total image"* in a few microseconds and forget all about multithreading?

Comment: I don't use openCV because I will use a camera, and the camera fill the buffer in an array of unsigned char. Moreother, opencv do not use multithread with the function accumulate, and taking into account the number of pixels (48Mp), it is more efficient to use openmp, and do it in parallel thread, that mean that the camera send an image (around 400 ms), and in the same time, I accumulate image to calculate the average image, with openmp

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't know it was a 48MP image. What camera is it please and how do you read from it exactly?

Comment: Also, maybe you can read an image and then start a new thread to read the next image but process the current image in the thread that already has the data hot in its cache? Alsop, have you tried using `memcpy()` to copy the data to another thread instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: It is baumer LXG-500. The company provides SDK. I receive image through datagramsocket. As the compagny provides the SDK, I get the image with :

BGAPI2::Buffer* pBufferFilled = pDataStream->GetFilledBuffer(1000);

And then I have access to the image with pBufferFilled->GetMemPtr()

Your first proposal is a nice idea but enforce 2 connections with the camera, and I am not sure that is most an efficient solution. 
Maybe using memcpy() could be a good idea, I will try to investigate that way. I am totaly novice with multithreading. I will let you know. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

C++ has native support for this through [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/). You can use it to perform both functions at once, and then synchronize them at the end.

However, for the problem you're trying to solve, you'll need to also use a [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to synchronize access to your container of images. This is because STL containers (I'm assuming you're using one) are not thread-safe, so if you attempt to write to a container or even just use its iterators in a multithreaded scenario, you can end up accessing invalidated iterators or references.